# JavaScript not functioning correctly in JSReport

Tags: javascript, jsreport

trying to use `document.getElementById()` in jsreport using the scripts section on the left menu, but it reports back

> Error occured - Error during rendering report: document is not defined

What gives?  This is simple JavaScript to target a particular ID.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: `document.getElementById("#showUpdatedRecordsFalse").style.visibility = "false";`

Comment: Also tried using jQuery within the renderer as such:  `$("#showUpdatedRecordsFalse").css( "visibility", "false" );`

Comment: How are you targeting the id though?  You've target the whole document.  Also, was in the report itself or was it in the script file?  Tried using jQuery in the script file and it didn't like it.

Comment: Wasn't worried about targeting an ID yet as you're currently failing to get document object, so any attempt at getting an ID would fail regardless.And I spoke too soon, $(document) did not work for me.

Comment: It's looking more and more like jsreport doesn't have the functionality of `document` within the script file.  I can access the document (e.g. `document.write("hello world");`) in the document itself but when I use `doument.write` within the script file I get the "Error occured - Error during rendering report: document is not defined" error.  I also cannot target an id in the document from the script being in the document with `document.getElementById();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is asynchronous related.  the `document.getElementById` must come after the the element you want to target is built.  So putting the script at the bottom of the page fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts that are included as part of the report generation request rather than inline with the template do not contain document or any other objects generated by the browser.

If you are trying to use Javascript to modify the document, you are almost certainly doing something wrong.  It's not meant to generate interactive content, so your template and data should already be fixed by the time you send the request.  You can probably work around this with require.js, but why would you?  If you are really generating a report, you can do everything ahead of time before you ever request output.

Comment: Yes, Jan explained that.  That's why the JavaScript needs to be inline.

Comment: But really, you shouldn't have to put any Javascript inline because this tool is meant to be used with fixed data and templates.  The inclusion of scripts is for things like formatting numbers (which you can do ahead of time) and creating charts and other graphics (which you can do ahead of time).  You should take a step back and ask yourself why you are trying to manipulate the DOM in your report instead of changing the template or data before you make the request to generate the report.

Comment: Programmatically, I'm hiding div's if there is no data to fill that particular div.  The reports are dynamic as is the data.  If there's no data, I want to display a div that says there's no data, otherwise I want to show a div that formats the data properly.  This has to be done within the JavaScript unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You can do that easily with the templating engines that jsreport has built-in.  e.g.,
`{{if foo.length === 0}}<content></content>{{/if}} {{if foo.length !== 0}}<othercontent></othercontent>{{/if}}`

Comment: Didn't realize that.  My JavaScript works, but this is less code.  Will have to give it a try.